# Fetch substring from right side

Tags: oracle, substr

I am using oracle. i have a column "ITEM_FINAL" consisting of a string which is a combination of 2 records.

```
ITEM_FINAL = ITEM_ID + ITEM
```

I need to segregate ITEM_FINAL and put them into 2 different columns ITEM_ID and ITEM.
However the length of the ITEM_ID is not constant, it can be 1 or 10 or 999 (till 3 digits).
ITEM is constant and it will be 5 digits always.

Eg. ITEM_FINAL = 1256789 (combination of 12 + 56789) or 256789 (combination of 2 + 56789)

I can fetch ITEM details with help of substr

```
select substr(ITEM_FINAL,-5) from dual;
```

It will give the last 5 digits (56789) which is constant. How can i fetch the remaining string from 6th position till the start irrespective of length from right hand side for ITEM_ID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select substr(ITEM_FINAL, 1, length(ITEM_FINAL)-5) ITEM_ID, 
       substr(ITEM_FINAL,-5) ITEM 
 from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you!! It solved. have to learn length function :)